# How to prevent DISK from changing MBR to an Hybrid MBR

Tags: boot, partitioning

I had a problem with the EFI partition after I installed Ubuntu on an external drive.  I deleted the EFI partition and rebuilt it. Then when I ran boot-repair, it revert back to MBR mode instead of GPT.  I changed that using gdisk.

But since then, every time I modify a partition (like increasing its size), DISK updates the MBR (or the boot sector).  Not sure how it is supposed to be called.  But it sounds like it might think I should be in MBR mode. So it writes the first three partitions to the MBR and it becomes an Hybrid MBR.   Windows cannot boot with Hybrid MBR.

I fix this by using gdisk in expert mode to "create a new protective MBR".  What I understand, this protective MBR is supposed to tell the software not to update the boot sector with the partitions.

After this, the MBR data look like this

```
Disk size is 1953525168 sectors (931.5 GiB)
MBR disk identifier: 0x00000000
MBR partitions:

Number  Boot  Start Sector   End Sector   Status      Code
   1                     1   1953525167   primary     0xEE
```

This is fine but if I change any partition with DISK, it will convert back the MBR into an Hybrid MBR.  How can I fix this?

Comment: MBR is the first sector the disk (sector 0); called the *Master Boot Record*. It's a standard going back to 1982, with the sector being reserved for that purpose; and sits outside of the Partition Table (be it *legacy* or DOS/MBR or GUID/GPT) as they start at sector 1.

Comment: Same issue here. This thread is almost a year old and I find many mentions on the internet about the issue but nobody has had success in almost a decade. It still exists in certain circumstances. I have spent 3 days trying to get windows and Ubuntu to play nice together on a GPT disk but Ubuntu keeps breaking the boot capability of windows because it keeps changing the disk to "hybrid mbr." Why would Ubuntu force users to have only hybrid disks.